# LinkedBlockingQueue#enqueue() what does the statement in the method mean?

Tags: java

```
LinkedBlockingQueue blockedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

blockedQueue.offer(1);
```

And then go to LinkedBlockingQueue#enqueue();

```
before enter enqueue(), "blockedQueue.offer(1);" I got a Node@xxx998(1) from Node node = new Node(1),

 private void enqueue(Node<E> node) {

// assert putLock.isHeldByCurrentThread();

// assert last.next == null;

last = last.next = node;

}
```

then the program run through

```
"last = last.next = node;", and I got :

last = Object@xxx998(1),

last.next = null,

node = Node@xxx998(1).
```

then I don't know why the statement would work the answer like that, especially I don't know why "last.next=null".

I search on the Internet for hour or so, and didn't find something about the "a=b=c" statement syntax, I found some "a=b=c=0" but these are useless for my case.

Comment: `last = last.next = node` means that the value of `node` is assigned to `last.next` and to `last`, in that order, i.e. right-to-left. It means that the `next` field of the "old" `last` is updated, before the `node` becomes the "new" `last`.

Comment: @Andreas thanks your good explaination about the "old" last and "new" last , now I know that the 'last.next' changed twice... once was directly change by "last.next=node", and then indirectly change by "last=node", because of 'node.next=null'.

Answer (score 0):

So consider what this operation does:

```
last = last.next = node
```

From the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

> All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; **assignment operators are evaluated right to left**.

So we apply that to what your equation, we get the following steps:

```
 last = last.next = node
     [2]         [1]
```

Running through it:

1:

```
 last = last.next = node
         [node]
```

2:

```
 last = last.next = node
[node]     [?]
```

Note that **none** of these operations have modified `node` itself.  So when you set `last` to `node`, it is now referencing the same untouched object that `node` is, and thus, `last.next` is the exact same as `node.next` (which could very well be null, as is shown in your case).

Comment: thanks！I forgot the member 'next' of 'node', now I got it.